# How can select multiple values which have same id from a mysql table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL table like this.

```
-------------------------------
      id | code
---------|---------------------
    1    | 1
    1    | 2
    1    | 3
    2    | 1
    2    | 2
    2    | 3
--------------------------------
```

Then I want to select id and get id's code.For example in this table I want to get id 's count where id has 1 and 2 code value.

Like this

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT id) as cnt FROM mytable WHERE code HAVE 1 AND 2
```

This is only for illustrate.

How can we do this?

Comment: but its naot same question.Multiple same id has different values from my table

Comment: Just use `WHERE code IN (1,2)`...

Comment: Try this: SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(id)) as count FROM tab tab1 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tab WHERE tab1.id = id AND code = 1) 
        AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tab WHERE tab1.id = id AND code = 2)